# Accessing different model elements in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am inexperienced in Rails (version 4.2.5) and struggle with how views access database elements. I have worked through a number of different tutorials but still don't really understand why it doesn't work the way I think it does!

I have models that have been set up with references which I believe that establishes foreign keys in the database. I want to edit entries in the database that belong in a different model.

So, a `Wines` is a model that references `Winemakers`.

```
class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :winemaker
end
```

In my `_edit_form.html.erb` file I have the following code which works but does not give me what I want:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@wine) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :winemaker_id %>
  <%= f.text_field :winemaker_id %>
</div>
```

This produces a simple box and in the box the integer that is `winemaker_id` is displayed but what I want is the actual name of the winemaker. I have tried `:winemaker_id.name`, `@winemaker.name` and many variations on those theme but I clearly do not understand how this works. I have tried reading various documentation but I am none the wiser.

Can someone please explain in simple terms how accessing different models works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Winemaker model has been defined as follows:

```
class Winemaker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wines
end
```

That means you can write the followings:

```
@winemaker.wines - returns all the wines belongs to a winemaker
@wine.winemaker  - returns the winemaker to whom the wine belongs
```

If you want to show and edit the Winemaker name from Wine form, then you can do it using **accepts_nested_attributes_for**

Just modify your Wine model as follows:

```
class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :winemaker
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :winemaker
end
```

Now you can make a small change to your form as follows:

```
<%= form_for @wine do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :winemaker do |w|%>
    <%= w.text_field :name%>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Many thanks, that was what I was looking for: I want to show the individual entries in the way you described.

Comment: Hi @fatherdamo, If this solution has solved your problem, then you can upvote my answer above.   
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@wine) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :winemaker_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:winemaker_id, Winemaker.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
```

Have a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select for more information.